# Grouping dates by periods and id using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of events by ID and would like to group them in two week periods. The two weeks should start whenever the first event occurs for each ID. The grouped event data should look something like the following,

```
ID    Date          Group
<dbl> <date>        <dbl>
1     2018-01-01    1
1     2018-01-02    1
1     2018-01-02    1
1     2018-02-01    2
1     2018-03-01    3
2     2018-01-01    4
2     2018-04-01    5

dat = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Date = structure(c(17532, 
17533, 17533, 17563, 17591, 17532, 17622), class = "Date"), Group = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Group"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I was originally thinking of lagging by ID and filtering for events that happen within a two week period, but there may be many events that correspond to a single two week period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` and `seq` to round to the nearest two week cutoff, then `group_indices` to make an increasing index:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(g = cut(Date, seq(first(Date), max(Date) + 14, by="2 weeks")) %>% as.character) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(g = group_indices(., ID, g))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID       Date Group     g
  <int>     <date> <int> <int>
1     1 2018-01-01     1     1
2     1 2018-01-02     1     1
3     1 2018-01-02     1     1
4     1 2018-02-01     2     2
5     1 2018-03-01     3     3
6     2 2018-01-01     4     4
7     2 2018-04-01     5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the difference of adjacent 'Date's with `difftime` specifying the `unit` as "week", check if the difference is greater than 2, and get the cumulative sum

```
dat %>%
    mutate(GroupNew = cumsum(abs(difftime(Date, lag(Date, 
              default = first(Date)), unit = "week")) > 2) + 1)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#     ID Date       Group GroupNew
#  <int> <date>     <int>    <dbl>
#1     1 2018-01-01     1        1
#2     1 2018-01-02     1        1
#3     1 2018-01-02     1        1
#4     1 2018-02-01     2        2
#5     1 2018-03-01     3        3
#6     2 2018-01-01     4        4
#7     2 2018-04-01     5        5
```